# Unable to implement custom log in in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

I want to implement custom login for wordpress users. But unable to match passwords when login. Dont know what encryption I need to use for password. Am using wp_hash_password() to encrypt password but it is not working for me. I am using like this:

```
  $username =$_POST['username'];
  $hash = wp_hash_password( $_POST['password']) ;
  $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE `user_login` =  '".$username."' AND `user_pass` = '".$hash."'");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

wp_hash_password function needs two parameters

```
wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );
```

Comment: I need to compare password entered with the password stored in database.

Comment: for that you can use function <?php wp_check_password( $password, $hash, $user_id ) ?>

Comment: you can get user id by username also